# C++: How to avoid vector from being destroyed after returning from method?

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to overload the division operator `/` for a `Polynomial` class, but the algorithm in itself is irrelevant. The problem is C++ seems to be corrupting my polynomial when I try to return it for some unknown reason.

This is the relevant part of the class:

```
class Polynomial
{
    public:
        .........
        Polynomial &operator/(const double &) const;
    private:
        int DEGREE;
        std::vector<double> poly_terms; // stores the polynomial coefficients
        .........
}
```

And this is the method that I can't get to work properly:

```
Polynomial &Polynomial::operator/(const double &rhs) const
{
    Polynomial result(10); //create new polynomial object with a maximum degree of 10
    double buffer;

    for(int i = 0; i <= DEGREE; i++)
    {
        buffer = poly_terms[i]; //poly_terms is of type vector<double>
        result.setCoeff(i, buffer / rhs); //this method assigns (buffer / rhs) to the i-th index of result's vector data-member.
    }
    return result; //return Polynomial instance
}
```

Right before the `return` clause is executed, a debugger shows that all data-members of the `result` object have their values correctly set as the algorithm was supposed to set them, including the `vector` data-member. So before `return` returns, `result` is 100% correctly built and thus the method's logic seems fine so far.

But everything monumentally fails right after the `return` statement is executed. For some reason the returned object gets its `vector` data-member changed to an empty `vector` (strangely, all other data-member that aren't objects, like `DEGREE`, are left fine as they were). I'm not sure if it's the same vector object that got emptied somehow, or if if it's a failed copy of the polynomial object which contains this vector object.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can avoid it?

**UPDATE1:**
I should mention that I also tried creating the `Polynomial` object in this method by using `new`. And I also tried not returning a reference by removing the `&` so having a header like `Polynomial Polynomial::operator/(const double &rhs) const`. But both of these produced similar unwanted effects on the `vector` data-member.

**UPDATE2:**
It seems I was able to track down the problem thanks to those who mentioned that I should not return a reference. The problem was this together with needing to overload the copy constructor and overloading the assignment operator to manually perform the copy of the vector data-member (not sure if both were needed, I just implemented all 3 of these things and now it works perfectly). Thanks to everyone for helping troubleshoot this.

Comment: Don't return the polynomial by reference.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: You have created `result` on the stack, whereas you need to create it on the heap with `new`.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, you're returning a reference to a temporary. Just return by value and problem solved.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Why bring dynamic memory allocation into it?  It is not needed at all.

Comment: You can return `Polynomial` by value and use a xvalue copy constructor `Polynomial(Polynomial&& source)` to receive the result by swap operations.

Comment: @Franck the term you're looking for is *Forwarding Reference* the standards committee finally selected a final name for an `&&` reference

Comment: @Mgetz A forwarding reference is `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter.  That's not the case for just a move constructor.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't warn you about returning a reference to local variable, upgrade it now.

Comment: The convention of returning a reference only makes sense if the reference is to `*this` or to a member of the class. In this case you have neither.

Comment: *And I also tried not returning a reference by removing the & so having a header like Polynomial Polynomial::operator/(const double &rhs) const*. This is the correct way of doing things. If you still have a problem, ask a question accompanied by a [mcve].

Comment: Returning the local vector by reference is definitely a bug, never do that. You should return by value. If you still have a problem it is not because you are returning by value so please post a minimal amount of code that reproduces the bug.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you return a reference to a local variable. Any code that will use the variable will be undefined behavior. There's a simple solution for your case: remove the `&`

```
// Notice that the function is not returning a reference anymore
Polynomial Polynomial::operator/(const double &rhs) const
{
    Polynomial result(10); //create new polynomial object with a maximum degree of 10
    double buffer;

    for(int i = 0; i <= DEGREE; i++)
    {
        buffer = poly_terms[i]; //poly_terms is of type vector<double>
        result.setCoeff(i, buffer / rhs); //this method assigns (buffer / rhs) to the i-th index of result's vector data-member.
    }
    return result; //return Polynomial
}
```

You might think it will slow your code because it copies the variable `result`. This is false. Your code will use copy elision. That means there's no copy made form the return statement.

Even if your compiler is dumb and won't use copy elision, it will use the move constructor of your class, and it's still much faster than a copy.

To read more about copy elision, check the documentation page here: [Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Answer (score 3):

At least in Visual studio this code should give you a warning, because you're using a reference to a temporary object that will be destroyed, so you're using a reference to youdontknowwhat. It's undefined behaviour.

You can simply return `result` by value in order to solve the problem. If the vector is big and you're worried about performance of returning by value, you can set a move constructor for `Polynomial` in which you move the vector instead than copying it.

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems with your code (though not all of them are causing your troubles) :

1. As others pointed out, return the reference of an object that dies as soon as the program exits the operator overloading function. You can just return the Polynomial object
2. You loop with an index from 0 to DEGREE (so DEGREE + 1 items are modified). I assume DEGREE is something defined from the int input parameter of the Polynomial constructor. I would expect the loop to be defined from 0 to DEGREE - 1
3. I also would expect the "results" Polynomial object to be instantiated with DEGREE degrees instead of the hardcoded 10

Comment: 1. Yes this seems to be one key factor relative to why the problem happens.
2. DEGREE stores an int value of the greatest exponent in the polynomial, so the size of the vector is (degree + 1). My bad for not including it as it was part of the algorithm and felt it was not relevant to the problem.
3. You are absolutely correct. In my actual code that 10 is replaced by DEGREE. I just put 10 in my example to try to make it easier to read.
Thanks for your observations.

Comment: the use of DEGREE is probably correct - a polynomial of degree 2 has 3 terms (0, 1, 2) etc.